# Google Cloud KMS (Hardware)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I hope someone can point me in the right direction or where I can find this information. I am trying to find out what is the underlying hardware Google Cloud uses for KMS management. I ask because we are thinking of getting a code signing certificate and they may ask us how is the HSM being stored on the Google cloud platform.

Is it: Marvell LiquidSecurity devices (formerly Cavium LiquidSecurity). I picked this up from this article: https://icedev.pl/posts/setting-up-ev-code-signing-google-hsm-fips-140-2/